# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_highgui in java.library.path

Tags: java, javacv

just installed javaCV. I imported all the jars in the project but when i eun this code i get that error:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvShowImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvWaitKey;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_GAUSSIAN;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvSmooth;

IplImage img = cvLoadImage("HelloWorld.jpg");
cvShowImage("Hello-World", img);
cvSmooth(img, img, CV_GAUSSIAN, 13);
cvShowImage("Blur-Image", img);
cvWaitKey();
cvReleaseImage(img);
```

from what is it caused?

Comment: i've also installed openvc but nothing

Comment: path and classpath are all setted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

In the main file and it works.. Just need this line of code